# Store php generated JSON string in a CSV file

Tags: php, json, csv

I am trying to generate a JSON string using php from an array, and I would like to store that string in a csv file, also with PHP. I want to do this, because I am working with a quite large amount of data, and I would like to use MySQL's `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to populate and update my database table.

This is the code I have:

```
$tmpFileProducts = 'path/to/file';
$tmpFileProductsHandler= fopen($tmpFileProducts, 'w');
foreach ($attributeBatch as $productId => $batch) {
    fputcsv($tmpFileProductsHandler, array($productId, $batch['title'], $batch['parsed'], json_encode($batch['attributes'])), "|", "\"");
}
```

My problem is, that when I am creating the CSV file, the JSON double-quotes are not escaped, thus I end up with simmilar lines in my csv file:

```
43541|"telefon mobil 3l 2020 4g "|"2020-12-05 17:38:19"|"{""color"":""dark chrome"",""memory_value"":4294967296,""storage_value"":68719476736,""sim_slot"":""dual""}"
```

My first possible solution would be, to change the `string enclosure` of my CSV file, but what enclosure should I use, to ensure no conflicts could arrise with the inner json column? I am in complete control of the array that is stringified, it will only contain ASCII characters, in it.

Would there be a way, to keep the current `string enclosure`, and instead escape the JSON string somehow? Later on, I will need to fetch the data that is included to the database, and convert it to an array again.

**DISCLAIMER:** I am well aware that instead of storing the data as a JSON string, I could store it in a specific relational table (which I am also doing), but I would need quick access to this data, for a background script that is running, and I would like to save on the time of the queries, to the relational table, as when the background script will use this data, it doesn't need to search in it.

**Follow up question:** as I am explicitly telling the `fputcsv` function what to use as `string enclosure` shouldn't it automatically escape all the simmilar inner strings?

Comment: Have you tried using a single quote as the enclosure character?

Comment: @NigelRen what if I have a single quote somewhere in my array that is stringified with JSON?

Comment: The quotes are actually properly quoted in your example above?! One quote becomes two quotes in CSV (RFC 4180)... But why not leave it as JSON? Its also text and also a structured format.